# node.js mkdir enonent when passed a string

Tags: node.js, error-handling, mkdir

I'm trying to build folders with a string, but I keep erroring out, everything looks good, but I'm obviously missing something, any help would be great.

```
var setFile = 'dijit/analysis/images/'
folders = setFile.substr(0,setFile.lastIndexOf('/'));

fs.mkdir(folders, function(err){
  console.log('problem: ' + err);
});
```

**Error:** `Error: ENOENT, mkdir 'dijit/analysis/images'`

Thanks,

Comment: Do the `dijit` and `dijit/analysis` directories already exist? Are you perhaps looking for https://www.npmjs.org/package/mkdirp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fs.mkdir can able to built only a single folder. You are trying to create a folder inside a non existing folder. This problem can be solved by [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.org/package/fs.extra) module of npm. Following code should fulfill your need.

```
var setFile = 'dijit/analysis/images/',
    fsExtra = require('fs-extra'),
    folders = setFile.substr(0, setFile.lastIndexOf('/'));

fsExtra.mkdirp(folders, function(err) {
    console.log('problem: ' + err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Kundu's comment answers this problem, but if you want a different solution there is plenty over at [How to create full path with node's fs.mkdirSync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645738/how-to-create-full-path-with-nodes-fs-mkdirsync)