# Is it possible to create a dir in Node like "mkdir -p" does?

Tags: node.js, mkdir

Is it possible to use the `fs` API to create a directory and all  necessary subdirectories like the `-p` parameter does when using the `mkdir` command?

Comment: This is an answer which I wrote to another similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44410793/2834139

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create full path with node's fs.mkdirSync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645738/how-to-create-full-path-with-nodes-fs-mkdirsync)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either write your own version or use a module like [mkdirp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp)

Comment: Note that ever since Node added `recursive: true` to the built-in `mkdir` function, this answer is no longer the right answer.

Answer (score 54):

Use [`fs.mkdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsrmsyncpath-options) with the `recursive: true` option:

```js
fs.mkdirSync('/tmp/a/apple', { recursive: true });
```

Comment: Note that this API is available since v10.12.0. This answer is cleaner than the accepted answer because it does not require installing dependencies.

Comment: Beware, I just wasted hours with weird issues where the node process froze so badly I could not kill it nor restart WSL, and had to reboot. This is NOT safe!

Comment: @Killroy Sounds like you have a really weird setup, because it's been part of Node for years now. Maybe file a bug with the Node folks instead? But it's almost certainly something else interfering.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a NPM package called `fs-extra` that conveniently allows you to do this:

```js
const fs = require("fs-extra");

async function createFolder(folder) {
  try {
    await fs.ensureDirSync(folder); // guarantees the directory is created, or error.
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error('You do not have the right permissions to make this folder.');
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to import fs-extra if you just need mkdirp. Node's own `mkdir` has had this functionality built in for years (and definitely at the time of this answer) in the form of the `recursive` option.