# Why error while dynamically creating directory in nodejs in ubuntu server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu

I am trying to create the directory in public/data folder to place my read data but Getting this error while creating the directory dynamically in `nodejs`.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir './public/data/folder'
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:753:3)
    at /home/ubuntu/New/routes/index.js:589:14
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:141:20)
```

I have implemented my code like this by checking the folder exist or not and creating the folder when not exist using `mkdirsync()`

```
var dd = './public/data/'+ id;
 if (!fs.existsSync(dd)) 
        {
          fs.mkdirSync(dd,'0777', true);
          console.log("Directory Created!!");
      }

Directory Created!!
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create full path with node's fs.mkdirSync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645738/how-to-create-full-path-with-nodes-fs-mkdirsync)

Comment: I think you should check if intermediate directories also exist because it is possible that public or public/data may not exist

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This solved issue, Running the npm with root permission

Solution:

sudo npm install -g PACKAGE-NAME --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root

Comment: Please don't use root permissions.

Answer (score 2):

`mkdirSync` accepts an option property `recursive` (default is *false*).
Check out the [guide](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_options)

So you could use:

```
fs.mkdirSync('/dir1/dir2', { recursive: true });
```

Comment: Getting same error `ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/dir1/dir2'`, running from build.