# express fileupload : no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express-file package. I use it like this:

```
const upload = require('express-fileupload');
app.use(upload({
    createParentPath: true
}));
```

This is how I store:

```
await req.files.main_image.mv('./public/images/movies/'+main_image);
```

I already have public/images directory created. I don't have movies directory in public/images directory though.

**When It works:** If I have /public/images/movies directory already created, it works

**When it doesn't work**: If I don't have /public/images/movies directory created, but have /public/images directory. Then it says:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Users\glagh\Desktop\Work\MoviesAdviser\public\images\movies\1554741546720-8485.11521.brussels.the-hotel-brussels.amenity.restaurant-AD3WAP2L-13000-853x480.jpeg

What to do so that it automatically creates /movies directory and put the image there?

Answer (score 1):

Express-fileupload uses the following [code](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload/blob/master/lib/utilities.js#L112) to create the directory-path which you pass to the `.mv` function:

```
const checkAndMakeDir = function(fileUploadOptions, filePath){
  //Check upload options were set.
  if (!fileUploadOptions) return false;
  if (!fileUploadOptions.createParentPath) return false;
  //Check whether folder for the file exists.
  if (!filePath) return false;
  const parentPath = path.dirname(filePath);
  //Create folder if it is not exists.
  if (!fs.existsSync(parentPath)) fs.mkdirSync(parentPath); 
  return true;
};
```

The problem is that `fs.mkdirSync()` does not create the full path with the parent directories you specifiy (note that you'd use `mkdir -p` on the shell to create the whole folder structure) -> checkout [How to create full path with node's fs.mkdirSync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645738/how-to-create-full-path-with-nodes-fs-mkdirsync) for more information.

What you could do is use a module like `fs-extra` and use its [function](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/HEAD/docs/ensureDir.md) `ensureDir` which would create the corresponding parent directories (if they don't exist yet) before calling the `.mv()` function.
Or in case you're node version is >= 10 use the native `{rescursive:true}` option which you can pass to `fs.mkdirSync`.

Comment: @Nika Kurashvili: Any news on this?