# I want to create a dir structure /A/B/file.js in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I want to create directory structure ./a/b/file.js. Here 'a', 'b' are directories and 'file.js' is created within 'a', 'b'. At once I want to create this file structure.

Let me know how to do this?

**file.js**

```
let fs = require('fs');
 let path4 = require('path');   
module.exports = {
    test
}

function test () {
let filepath = path4.resolve(process.env.TEMP + path4.sep + "A" + path4.sep  + "B" + path4.sep +  "file.js"); 
  if( fs.existsSync(filepath)) {
    console.log("file already exist");
  } else {
   fs.mkdirSync(filepath);
  }
}
```

But when I run this script , I see this error Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,

Comment: please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645738/how-to-create-full-path-with-nodes-fs-mkdirsync

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40686853/5979775)